# how to stop handler from executing

Tags: android

I created a custom [compound control](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound) to use in my list view to show a timer. In it, I use a handler to update the displayed timer value every 1 sec. The problem is that this handler keeps executing, even if the list item is scrolled out of view or even if i exit the app. How do i stop this handler from executing?

I tried `handler.removeCallbacks()`, but it does not seem to work.

```
public class TimerLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TimerLayout";
    Date startTime;
    TextView tv_timer;
    Button btn_cancelTimer;
    Runnable updateTimerThread;
    Handler handler;

    public TimerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, this, true);
        tv_timer = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
        btn_cancelTimer = (Button) ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1);
        handler = new Handler();

        updateTimerThread = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //calculate total time
                long timeInMilliSeconds = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime.getTime();
                int secs = (int) (timeInMilliSeconds / 1000) % 60 ;
                int mins = (int) ((timeInMilliSeconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
                int hours   = (int) ((timeInMilliSeconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
                tv_timer.setText(String.format("%02d", hours)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)
                        );

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }

        };

    }

    public void start(Date startTime) {

        if (startTime != null) {
            this.startTime = startTime;
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
        }

    }

    btn_cancelTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: add more thread behavior so you can observe/ stop your thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657709/what-happens-to-java-thread-after-a-join-call-with-timeout

Comment: @RobertRowntree To make the thread behave, i need to know whether this control is visible or not. That's where i am stuck. Is there a callback that lets me know when a layout comes into and goes out of view?

Comment: dont know about your specifics... but , in general, your OP on thread would be explain some in any , git , impl of a 'recorder' because they all use a start/stop button on UI that controls a thread doing actual recording. your timer is similar.... https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/BooRecorder.java

Comment: keeping track of UI state falls under MVC state management and whatever you do for that. I guess you could callback to an interface in your Activity in order to track your UI state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the framework's chronometer instead and stop it in the `onPause()` of the activity/fragment. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26034525/2105986). The chronometer already has it's own handler and exposes methods to start and stop it.