# chronometer in list view gets leaked sometimes

Tags: android

I have a [chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) in my list view. The problem is that sometimes it gets leaked i.e. i can see the `OnChronometerTickListener` executing every second even after i have navigated to another tab or scrolled the list view item out of view or even pressed the `Home` button. It seems a waste of resources, since i need it to run only when it is actually visible.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? Note that it happens only sometimes.

```
public class TimerLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TimerLayout";
    Button btn_endTimer;
    Button btn_cancelTimer;
    Chronometer cmt_timer;
    Runnable updateTimerThread;
    Handler handler;

    public TimerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, this, true);
        cmt_timer = (Chronometer) getChildAt(0);
        btn_endTimer = (Button) ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0);
        btn_cancelTimer = (Button) ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1);

        btn_endTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                cmt_timer.stop();
            }
        });

        btn_cancelTimer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                cmt_timer.stop();
            }
        });

        cmt_timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onChronometerTick.objectid=" + System.identityHashCode(TimerLayout.this));}

            }
        });

    }

    public void init(Date startTime){
        cmt_timer.stop();
        if(startTime!=null){
            Date now = new Date();
            long elapsedTime = now.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
            cmt_timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedTime);
            cmt_timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

I call the `init` method of this class in the `bindView()` method of my `cursorAdaptor` to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to stop the chronometers in the `onPause()` of the fragment/activity.

So i create a class to hold the chronometers :

```
public class ChronometerHolder {
    private WeakHashMap<Date, Chronometer> chronometerMap;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ChronometerHolder";

    public ChronometerHolder() {
        chronometerMap = new WeakHashMap<Date, Chronometer>();
    }

    public void add(Date dt_startTime, Chronometer chronometer){
        chronometerMap.put(dt_startTime, chronometer);
    }

    public void remove(Date dt_startTime){
        chronometerMap.remove(dt_startTime);
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return chronometerMap.size();
    }

    public void startAll() {
        // start any chronometers that were paused
        if (chronometerMap.size() > 0) {
            Set<Entry<Date, Chronometer>> set = chronometerMap.entrySet();
            Iterator<Entry<Date, Chronometer>> iterator = set.iterator();
            Entry<Date, Chronometer> entry;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                entry = (Entry<Date, Chronometer>) iterator.next();
                entry.getValue().start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopAll() {
        // stop any chronometers that might be running
        if (chronometerMap.size() > 0) {
            Set<Entry<Date, Chronometer>> set = chronometerMap.entrySet();
            Iterator<Entry<Date, Chronometer>> iterator = set.iterator();
            Entry<Date, Chronometer> entry;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                entry = (Entry<Date, Chronometer>) iterator.next();
                entry.getValue().stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i make the below changes :

1. Return the chronometer object from `init()` :

   ```
   public Chronometer init(Date startTime){
       Chronometer obj = null;
       cmt_timer.stop();
       if(startTime!=null){
           Date now = new Date();
           long elapsedTime = now.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
           cmt_timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedTime);
           cmt_timer.start();
           obj = cmt_timer;
       }

       return obj;

   }
   ```
2. In the fragment, instantiate the holder class :

   ```
   ChronometerHolder chronometerHolder = new ChronometerHolder();
   ```
3. Every time you initialize the chrononmeter( in the `bindView()` of the `CursorAdapter`), add it to the holder :

   ```
   Chronometer tmpChronometer = viewHolder.myTimer.init(dt_hitSessionStartTime);
   if(tmpChronometer != null){
       chronometerHolder.add(dt_hitSessionStartTime, tmpChronometer);
   }
   ```
4. In `onPause()`, stop all the chronometers :

   ```
   chronometerHolder.stopAll();
   ```
5. In `onResume()`, start all the chronometers :

   ```
   chronometerHolder.startAll();
   ```

When the you press the Home button instead of exiting the app, and then open the app again, the `bindView()` calls are not executed. That means the chronometers are in a stopped state. So it has to be started in `onResume()` as done in #5.